# Enable left click in edit mode for linkify plugin for draftjs

Tags: javascript, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I was trying [draft-js-linkify-plugin](https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/plugin/linkify) for creating a simple rich text editor. I have a requirement that link should be clickable while I am editing the content.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a WYSIWYG editor type functionality.
You can use readOnly mode on draftJS. It will convert your text to corresponding html and it wont be editable.
Basically it works like a preview mode.
You will need two instances of the same component to make it work.
**isReadOnly will be true** for preview mode and **isReadOnly will be false** for edit mode.

Like so:

```
<Editor editorState={this.state.editorState}
                        placeholder={placeholderLabel}
                        handleKeyCommand={this.handleKeyCommand}
                        keyBindingFn={this.keyBindingFunction}
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                        readOnly={isReadOnly}
                        onEscape={this.onEscape}
                        plugins={this.state.plugins}
                        ref={this.editorRef}/>
```